# Musicbrainz database - MySQL lasts too much time to delete or insert

Tags: mysql, musicbrainz

I am trying to import the **Musicbrainz** db into a MySQL database using Perl scripts from [Churruka](https://github.com/hangar18cc/mbzdb), not the "official" ones due to not working properly (I consulted [here](https://github.com/elliotchance/mbzdb/issues/68)).

Now I have inserted all the tables except 'recording', whose size is **1.39 GB**. I have tried to insert the downloaded file two times. However, the insertions lasts too much and I'm afraid some configuration is not correctly set in MySQL. I just downloaded it for this import, so no more databases are present.

Both times, something happened to my laptop so I had to restart the process. I deleted all the rows from the 'recording' table to restart again, but the process lasts sooooo many seconds. Currently is **above 110000s** !!!

Any idea of how this process could be speeded up? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can enable slow query log in your my.cnf with 
`slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log` and check where is the bottleneck

Comment: The log was already activated but I cannot see anything regarding the DELETE statement. I think I will restart de service and try to insert the data again...

Comment: I have used DROP TABLE recording and restarted the INSERT again...

Comment: 66 hours later, the miracle took place Sun Aug  2 09:25:21 2015: Loading data into 'recording' (1 of 1)...
Done (66h  4m 32s)

Complete (66h  4m 32s)

Comment: Oh boy. It took that long for just 1.35 GB! It is the query inside a transaction or it is the script making some expensive transformation in the data before making the insert?

Comment: Unless you have a specific use case for using MySQL, musicbrainz has a docker container which makes set up of postgres db super easy and convenient - https://github.com/metabrainz/musicbrainz-docker